# Debug a Windows Mobile 5 Application on a Physical Device

Tags: visual-studio, windows-mobile

I'm trying to debug and test my application with a Dell Windows Mobile device using Visual Studio 2008. I can connect to the device and deploy it on to the device using ActiveSync. The problem I'm having now is that when debugging, after the project is deployed on to the device, the breakpoints are never hit and the application just runs by itself on the device. Visual Studio just hangs there and does nothing. I don't really know what's wrong with it... So frustrating...Help me!! Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure you're running the software in debug mode? You don't say whether it's a managed or native app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have all of the latest service packs for both Studio and the Compact Framework installed on your PC.  You're likely got a mismatch in versions.